# What is The Turkey Test?

Tags: testing, localization, internationalization, turkey-test

I came across the word 'The Turkey Test' while learning about code testing. I don't know really what it means.

What is Turkey Test? Why is it called so?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Turkey problem is related to software internationalization or simply to its misbehavior in various language cultures.

In various countries there are different standards, for example for writing dates (14.04.2008 in Turkey and 4/14/2008 in US), numbers (i.e. 123,45 in Poland and 123.45 in USA) and rules about character uppercasing (like in Turkey with letters i, I and ı).

As [Jeff Moser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869/jeff-moser) pointed below one such problem was pointed out by a Turkish user who found a bug in the `ToUpper()` function. There are more details in comments below.

However the problem is not limited to Turkey and to string conversions.

For example, in Poland and many other countries, dates and numbers are also written in a different manner.

Some links from [a Google search for the Turkey Test](http://www.google.pl/search?q=The+Turkey+Test) :

- [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)
  by Jeff Moser
- [What's Wrong With Turkey?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/)
  by Jeff Atwood

Comment: I called it "The Turkey Test" because a user in Turkey was the first to find a bug in our code that was triggered by a ToUpper() error that I described in the post.

Comment: "I have no idea why the problem has been called Turkey problem, because in Poland and many other European countries dates and numbers are also written with different manners."

It is mostly about uppercase/lowercase of the 'İ' letter. For example, Microsoft Service Trace Viewer tool is suffering from this problem. When you want to open a log file under Inetpub folder, what you get is an error message saying "'c:\ınetpub\...' cannot be opened"

Comment: It's because the Turkish case rules of the letter i/I are one of a handful of prominent examples of where proper international string handling has a fine-grained subtlety that no one is expecting, and thus tends to break code in very painful ways.  The letter i is very common in both English and Turkish, but you need to know which language you are using to properly upcase it.  This is especially painful when you have the quite common scenario of non-Turkish words being used in a Turkish context—you need to have per-string language settings!  Date formatting by contrast is child's play.

Answer (score 21):

[Here is described the turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

> Forget about Turkey, this won't even pass in the USA. You need a case insensitive compare. So you try:
>
> ```
> String.Compare(string,string,bool ignoreCase):
> ```
>
> ....
>
> Do any of these pass "The Turkey Test?"
>
> **Not a chance!**
>
> Reason: You've been hit with the "Turkish I" problem.
>
> As discussed by lots and lots of people, the "I" in Turkish behaves differently than in most languages. Per the Unicode standard, our lowercase "i" becomes "İ" (U+0130 "Latin Capital Letter I With Dot Above") when it moves to uppercase. Similarly, our uppercase "I" becomes "ı" (U+0131 "Latin Small Letter Dotless I") when it moves to lowercase.

Answer (score 13):

We write dates smaller to bigger like dd.MM.yyyy: 28.10.2010

We use '.'(dot) for thousands separator, and ','(comma) for decimal separator: 4.567,9

We have ö=>Ö, ç=>Ç, ş=>Ş, ğ=>Ğ, ü=>Ü, and **most importantly ı=>I and i => İ**; in other words, lower case of upper I is dotless and upper case of lower i is dotted.

People may have very stressful times because of meaningless errors caused by the above rules.

If your code properly runs in Turkey, it'll probably work anywhere.

Comment: Certainly agree with "*If your code properly runs in Turkey, it'll probably work anywhere.*"

Answer (score 4):

The so called "Turkey Test" is related to Software internationalization. One problem of globalization/internationalization are that date and time formats in different cultures can differ on many levels (day/month/year order, date separator etc).

Also, Turkey has some special rules for capitalization, which can lead to problems. For example, the Turkish "i" character is a common problem for many programs which capitalize it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

The link provided by @Luixv gives a comprehensive description of the issue.

The summary is that if your going to test your code on only one non-English locale, test it on Turkish.

This is because the Turkish has instances of most edge cases you are likely to encounter with localization, including "unusual" format strings and non-standard characters (such as a different capitalization rules for i).

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood has a blog article on same which is the first place I came across it myself.
in summary  attempting to run your application under a Turkish Locale is an excellent test
of your I18n.

here's jeffs [article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/)