# Bash: Split string into character array

Tags: string, bash

I have a string in a Bash shell script that I want to split into an array of characters, not based on a delimiter but just one character per array index. How can I do this? <strike>Ideally it would not use any external programs.</strike> Let me rephrase that. My goal is portability, so things like `sed` that are likely to be on any POSIX compatible system are fine.

Comment: `bash` is not a given if your platform is POSIX.

Comment: @tripleee neither are arrays.

Comment: Of course. I'm trying to make sense of the question.  Maybe the OP means to target Bash on an otherwise-POSIX system?

Comment: The original intention was to create a shell script that could be shared online without knowing much about the user's platform. So I wanted as much compatibility as possible, across OS X, Ubuntu, etc. I don't need 100% compatibility with exotic variations of Unix.

Comment: You can extract a single character with `${string:1:1}` _in bash_, but if you need to support POSIX sh you can't assume you have that, _or that you have arrays at all_.

Comment: And POSIX sh is not some weird exotic thing you never see in modern real-world systems. I mean, Debian's dash is basically a POSIX shell.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Try

```
echo "abcdefg" | fold -w1
```

*Edit: Added a more elegant solution suggested in comments.*

```
echo "abcdefg" | grep -o .
```

Comment: Despite the fact that an external command is used, +1 because of conciseness.

Comment: http://unstableme.blogspot.fi/2009/07/split-string-to-characters-in-bash.html has the rather elegant suggestion `echo "abcdefg" | grep -o .`

Comment: @xdazz it don't work on Unicode. Try this `echo "عمر" | fold -w1` It prints spaces and question marks. However @tripleee's solution `echo "عمر" | grep -o .` does work fine. Funny how small programs don't pass the http://stackoverflow.com/q/796986/161278 :). Thanks anyway for your elegant answer.

Comment: @OmarIthawi Thanks, added it to the answer.

Comment: @OmarIthawi: both of those variants work for me, on Mac OS X and Linux CentOS 6.5, so it seems it's not as simple as "the fold solution doesn't work with unicode".

Comment: Not unexpectedly the `fold` solution appears to be much (>6 times) faster than grep.

Comment: @OmarAl-Ithawi: your locale is maybe different than the one of eric.weathers or har-wradim? you can "force" a change of locale by using for example:  echo "something" | LC_ALL='C' fold -w1   (or different locales instead of C. use "locale -a" to see all availables for your system)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I tried to change the locale but it didn't work `$ fold`, mine is "fold (GNU coreutils) 8.25" on Ubuntu. This might be _the_ difference.

Comment: For @OmarAl-Ithawi's example, I get different results with different combinations of locale and command. On Debian GNU/Linux, only the combination of `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep -o .` works correctly and all the others just print rows of `?`. On Darwin, `LANG=C fold -w1` just prints out the string without any modification, `LANG=C grep -o .` prints rows of `?`, and the rest (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`) work correctly.

Comment: @OmarAl-Ithawi Actually I just tested and his original does work on unicode with fold version=8.22. Also his original answer works on Mac but the proposed alternative doesn't. I think the original answer is better.

Answer (score 42):

You can access each letter individually already without an array conversion:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo ${foo:0:1}
b
$ echo ${foo:1:1}
a
$ echo ${foo:2:1}
r
```

If that's not enough, you could use something like this:

```
$ bar=($(echo $foo|sed  's/\(.\)/\1 /g'))
$ echo ${bar[1]}
a
```

If you can't even use `sed` or something like that, you can use the first technique above combined with a while loop using the original string's length (`${#foo}`) to build the array.

**Warning:** the code below does not work if the string contains whitespace. I think [Vaughn Cato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930/bash-split-string-into-character-array/7579016#7579016) has a better chance at surviving with special chars.

```
thing=($(i=0; while [ $i -lt ${#foo} ] ; do echo ${foo:$i:1} ; i=$((i+1)) ; done))
```

Comment: don't forget to quote: `echo "$foo"`

Comment: the loop you suggested: `for i in $(seq ${#foo}); do echo "${foo:$i-1:1}"; done`

Comment: @wjandrea `seq` is non-POSIX.

Answer (score 17):

As an alternative to iterating over `0 .. ${#string}-1` with a for/while loop, there are two other ways I can think of to do this with *only bash*: using `=~` and using `printf`. (There's a third possibility using `eval` and a `{..}` sequence expression, but this lacks clarity.)

With the correct environment and NLS enabled in bash these will work with non-ASCII as hoped, removing potential sources of failure with older system tools such as `sed`, if that's a concern. These will work from bash-3.0 (released 2005).

Using `=~` and regular expressions, converting a string to an array in a single expression:

```
string="wonkabars"
[[ "$string" =~ ${string//?/(.)} ]]       # splits into array
printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"      # loop free: reuse fmtstr
declare -a arr=( "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}" ) # copy array for later
```

The way this works is to perform an expansion of `string` which substitutes each single character for `(.)`, then match this generated regular expression with grouping to capture each individual character into `BASH_REMATCH[]`. Index 0 is set to the entire string, since that special array is read-only you cannot remove it, note the `:1` when the array is expanded to skip over index 0, if needed.
Some quick testing for non-trivial strings (>64 chars) shows this method  is *substantially* faster than one using bash string and array operations.

The above will work with strings containing newlines, `=~` supports [POSIX ERE where `.` matches anything except NUL](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_02) by default, i.e. the regex is compiled without `REG_NEWLINE`. (The behaviour of POSIX text processing *utilities* is allowed to be different by default in this respect, and usually is.)

Second option, using `printf`:

```
string="wonkabars"
ii=0
while printf "%s%n" "${string:ii++:1}" xx; do 
  ((xx)) && printf "\n" || break
done
```

This loop increments index `ii` to print one character at a time, and breaks out when there are no characters left. This would be even simpler if the bash `printf` returned the number of character printed (as in C) rather than an error status, instead the number of characters printed is captured in `xx` using `%n`. (This works at least back as far as bash-2.05b.)

With bash-3.1 and `printf -v var` you have slightly more flexibility, and can avoid falling off the end of the string should you be doing something other than printing the characters, e.g. to create an array:

```
declare -a arr
ii=0
while printf -v cc "%s%n" "${string:(ii++):1}" xx; do 
    ((xx)) && arr+=("$cc") || break
done
```

Comment: I like to consider myself fairly decently knowledgeable in bash, but man there are constantly new things I'm learning. These are both really cool tricks, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

If your string is stored in variable x, this produces an array y with the individual characters:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#x} ]; do y[$i]=${x:$i:1};  i=$((i+1));done
```

Comment: This: `for (( i=0 ; i < ${#x} ; i++ )); do y[i]=${x:i:1}; done` looks more idiomatic for bash.

Comment: This is old but I want to say that bash reads the whole string every time it calculates its length, so putting it in a var would be good. alternatively, starting from the length and going down also works.

Answer (score 6):

The most simple, complete and elegant solution:

```
$ read -a ARRAY <<< $(echo "abcdefg" | sed 's/./& /g')
```

and test

```
$ echo ${ARRAY[0]}
  a

$ echo ${ARRAY[1]}
  b
```

*Explanation*: `read -a` reads the stdin as an array and assigns it to the variable ARRAY treating spaces as delimiter for each array item.

The evaluation of echoing the string to sed just add needed spaces between each character.

We are using [***Here String***](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) (<<<) to feed the stdin of the read command.

Answer (score 6):

I have found that the following works the best:

```
array=( `echo string | grep -o . ` )
```

(note the backticks)

then if you do: `echo ${array[@]}` ,
you get: `s t r i n g`

or: `echo ${array[2]}` ,
you get: `r`

Comment: Good solution. How the backticks works (in this case and in other usage cases)?

Comment: The backtick means execute the command between the 2 backticks and replace the backtick and what's in between with the output of that command.
The parenthesis create an array and assigns it to the variable "array" explicitly as the person asking the question requested.

Answer (score 5):

Pure Bash solution with no loop:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.'

# Need extglob for the replacement pattern
shopt -s extglob

# Split string characters into array (skip first record)
# Character 037 is the octal representation of ASCII Record Separator
# so it can capture all other characters in the string, including spaces.
IFS= mapfile -s1 -t -d $'\37' array <<<"${str//?()/$'\37'}"

# Strip out captured trailing newline of here-string in last record
array[-1]="${array[-1]%?}"

# Debug print array
declare -p array
```

Comment: Nice, U could: - create a function and  - post some samples!

Answer (score 3):

```
string=hello123

for i in $(seq 0 ${#string})
    do array[$i]=${string:$i:1}
done

echo "zero element of array is [${array[0]}]"
echo "entire array is [${array[@]}]"
```

The zero element of array is `[h]`. The entire array is `[h e l l o 1 2 3 ]`.

Comment: These substring extraction operations are superior to equivalent solutions that involve piping the string through a subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another on :), the stated question simply says 'Split string into character array' and don't say much about the state of the receiving array, and don't say much about special chars like   and control chars.

My assumption is that if I want to split a string into an array of chars I want the receiving array containing just that string and no left over from previous runs, yet preserve any special chars.

For instance the proposed solution family like

```
for (( i=0 ; i < ${#x} ; i++ )); do y[i]=${x:i:1}; done
```

Have left overs in the target array.

```
$ y=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
$ x=abc
$ for (( i=0 ; i < ${#x} ; i++ )); do y[i]=${x:i:1}; done
$ printf '%s ' "${y[@]}"
a b c 4 5 6 7 8
```

Beside writing the long line each time we want to split a problem, so why not hide all this into a function we can keep is a package source file, with a API like

```
s2a "Long string" ArrayName
```

I got this one that seems to do the job.

```
$ s2a()
> { [ "$2" ] && typeset -n __=$2 && unset $2;
>   [ "$1" ] && __+=("${1:0:1}") && s2a "${1:1}"
> }

$ a=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) ; printf '%s ' "${a[@]}"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 

$ s2a "Split It" a        ; printf '%s ' "${a[@]}"
S p l i t   I t
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text can contain spaces:

```
eval a=( $(echo "this is a test" | sed "s/\(.\)/'\1' /g") )
```

Comment: use the information from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7581114/394952 to display the characters stored in the array "a". Like this: `eval a=( $(echo "this is a test" | sed "s/\(.\)/'\1' /g") );v=0; echo Array: "${a[@]}"; while [[ $v -lt  ${#a[@]} ]];do echo -ne "$v:\t" ;   echo ${a[$v]}; let v=v+1;done`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo hello | awk NF=NF FS=
h e l l o
```

Or

```
$ echo hello | awk '$0=RT' RS=[[:alnum:]]
h
e
l
l
o
```

Comment: Warning: The result of using a null FS changes with awk implementation. It is explicitly [avoided by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04): «1.- If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified.». More specific: This fails: `echo hello | original-awk NF=NF FS=`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post/thread but with a new [feature](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061) of bash v5.2+ using the [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) `patsub_replacement` and the `=~` operator for regex. More or less same with @mr.spuratic post/answer.

```
str='There can be only one, the Highlander.'
regexp="${str//?/(&)}"
[[ "$str" =~ $regexp ]] &&
printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
```

Or by just: (which includes the whole string at index 0)

```
declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

---

If that is not desired, one can remove the value of the first index (index 0), with

```
unset -v 'BASH_REMATCH[0]'
```

instead of using `printf` or `echo` to print the value of the array `BASH_REMATCH`

---

One can check/see the value of the variable `"$regexp"` with either

```
declare -p regexp
```

Output

```
declare -- regexp="(T)(h)(e)(r)(e)( )(c)(a)(n)( )(b)(e)( )(o)(n)(l)(y)( )(o)(n)(e)(,)( )(t)(h)(e)( )(H)(i)(g)(h)(l)(a)(n)(d)(e)(r)(.)"
```

or

```
echo "$regexp"
```

---

Using it in a script, one might want to test if the `shopt` is enabled or not, although the manual says it is on/enabled by default.

Something like.

```
if ! shopt -q patsub_replacement; then
  shopt -s patsub_replacement
fi
```

---

But yeah, check the `bash` [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450604/how-to-get-the-bash-version-number) too! If you're not sure which version of `bash` is in use.

```
if ! ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 5 && BASH_VERSINFO[1] >= 2)); then
  printf 'No dice! bash version 5.2+ is required!\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

---

Space can be excluded from `regexp` variable, change it from

```
regexp="${str//?/(&)}"
```

To

```
regexp="${str//[! ]/(&)}"
```

and the output is:

```
declare -- regexp="(T)(h)(e)(r)(e) (c)(a)(n) (b)(e) (o)(n)(l)(y) (o)(n)(e) (t)(h)(e) (H)(i)(g)(h)(l)(a)(n)(d)(e)(r)(.)"
```

---

- Maybe not as efficient as the other post/answer but it is still a solution/option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store this in an array, you can do this:

```
string=foo
unset chars
declare -a chars
while read -N 1
do
    chars[${#chars[@]}]="$REPLY"
done <<<"$string"x
unset chars[$((${#chars[@]} - 1))]
unset chars[$((${#chars[@]} - 1))]

echo "Array: ${chars[@]}"
Array: f o o
echo "Array length: ${#chars[@]}"
Array length: 3
```

The final `x` is necessary to handle the fact that a newline is appended after `$string` if it doesn't contain one.

If you want to use NUL-separated characters, you can try this:

```
echo -n "$string" | while read -N 1
do
    printf %s "$REPLY"
    printf '\0'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK is quite convenient:

```
a='123'; echo $a | awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS=" "} {print $1,$2,$3}'
```

where `FS` and `OFS` is delimiter for read-in and print-out

Answer (score 0):

For those who landed here searching how to do this in [fish](https://fishshell.com/):

We can use the builtin `string` command (since v2.3.0) for string manipulation.

```
↪ string split '' abc
a
b
c
```

The output is a list, so array operations will work.

```
↪ for c in (string split '' abc)
      echo char is $c
  end
char is a
char is b
char is c
```

Here's a more complex example iterating over the string with an index.

```
↪ set --local chars (string split '' abc)
  for i in (seq (count $chars))
      echo $i: $chars[$i]
  end
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also need support for strings with newlines, you can do:

```
str2arr(){ local string="$1"; mapfile -d $'\0' Chars < <(for i in $(seq 0 $((${#string}-1))); do printf '%s\u0000' "${string:$i:1}"; done); printf '%s' "(${Chars[*]@Q})" ;}
string=$(printf '%b' "apa\nbepa")
declare -a MyString=$(str2arr "$string")
declare -p MyString
# prints declare -a MyString=([0]="a" [1]="p" [2]="a" [3]=$'\n' [4]="b" [5]="e" [6]="p" [7]="a")
```

As a response to Alexandro de Oliveira, I think the following is more elegant or at least more intuitive:

```
while read -r -n1 c ; do arr+=("$c") ; done <<<"hejsan"
```

Answer (score 0):

[zsh](https://www.zsh.org) solution: To put the scalar `string` variable into `arr`, which will be an array:

```
arr=(${(ps::)string})
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
declare -r some_string='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
declare -a some_array
declare -i idx

for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#some_string}; ++idx)); do
  some_array+=("${some_string:idx:1}")
done

for idx in "${!some_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$((idx)): ${some_array[idx]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a "bash" question, but please let me show you the perfect solution in zsh, a shell very popular these days:

```
string='this is a string'
string_array=(${(s::)string})  #Parameter expansion. And that's it!

print ${(t)string_array}  -> type array
print $#string_array -> 16 items
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash, no loop.

Another solution, similar to/adapted from [Léa Gris' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68907322/3079831), but using `read -a` instead of `readarray/mapfile` :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='azerty'

# Need extglob for the replacement pattern
shopt -s extglob

# Split string characters into array
# ${str//?()/$'\x1F'} replace each character "c" with "^_c".
# ^_ (Control-_, 0x1f) is Unit Separator (US), you can choose another
# character.
IFS=$'\x1F' read -ra array <<< "${str//?()/$'\x1F'}"

# now, array[0] contains an empty string and the rest of array (starting
# from index 1) contains the original string characters :
declare -p array

# Or, if you prefer to keep the array "clean", you can delete
# the first element and pack the array :
unset array[0]
array=("${array[@]}")
declare -p array
```

However, I prefer the shorter (and easier to understand for me), where we remove the initial `0x1f` before assigning the array :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='azerty'
shopt -s extglob

tmp="${str//?()/$'\x1F'}"              # same as code above
tmp=${tmp#$'\x1F'}                     # remove initial 0x1f
IFS=$'\x1F' read -ra array <<< "$tmp"  # assign array

declare -p array                       # verification
```