# How to get the Bash version number

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a script which requires the Bash version number in a simple short format.

I'm aware of `bash --version`, but this gives a long output:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

This could be cut down to the bit I want, `4.2.10`, by this:

```
bash --version | grep "bash" | cut -f 4 -d " " | cut -d "-" -f 1  | cut -d "(" -f 1
```

However, this feels like it would be prone to break if that message ever changed slightly for whatever reason.

Is there a better way to do this, and what is this better way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're running within a Bash shell, then the `$BASH_VERSION` environment variable should be set:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.8(1)-release
```

That should be easier and more reliable to parse. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for a list of environment variables set by the shell.

Comment: ... and with that I've discovered `$BASH_VERSINFO` with which I can build it using only the bits I need, for some reason the man page that is on my machine doesn't have any mention of the environment variables it sets. Thanks :)

Answer (score 40):

There's also a special array (BASH_VERSINFO) containing each version number in separate elements.

```
if ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 3))
then
  echo "Sorry, you need at least bash-3.0 to run this script."
  exit 1
fi
```

See *[9.1. Internal Variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)* for more information:

```
# Bash version information:

for n in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
  echo "BASH_VERSINFO[$n] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[$n]}"
done

# BASH_VERSINFO[0] = 3                      # Major version no.
# BASH_VERSINFO[1] = 00                     # Minor version no.
# BASH_VERSINFO[2] = 14                     # Patch level.
# BASH_VERSINFO[3] = 1                      # Build version.
# BASH_VERSINFO[4] = release                # Release status.
# BASH_VERSINFO[5] = i386-redhat-linux-gnu  # Architecture
                                            # (same as $MACHTYPE).
```

Answer (score 11):

To extract the first part:

```
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION%%[^0-9.]*}
4.2.10
```

Comment: Just the major version: `echo ${BASH_VERSION%%[^0-9]*}`

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSINFO`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an environment variable for this:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

yields

```
4.1.7(1)-release
```

on my machine.

Comment: Just a shell variable (visible inside bash only), not exported into the environment.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [FelixEnescu's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514057/45375):

To report the first 3 version-number components - e.g., `4.2.10` - via [built-in array shell variable `BASH_VERSINFO`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables):

```
$ bash -c 'IFS=.; echo "${BASH_VERSINFO[*]: 0:3}"'
4.2.10
```

If you're calling this from inside a Bash script, use a *subshell* in order to localize the effect of changing `IFS`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ver=$(IFS=.; echo "${BASH_VERSINFO[*]: 0:3}")  # -> e.g., $ver == '4.2.10'
```

**Explanation:**

- `IFS=.` sets the internal field separator to `.`, which ensures that when we print an array inside a double-quoted string later, the array's elements are joined with that separator.

  - Note that you can't just do `IFS=. echo ...` to transiently redefine IFS scoped to the the `echo` command, because shell [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) (the expansion of `${BASH_VERSINFO[*]: 0:3}`, in this case) happens *before* `echo` is invoked.  Therefore, two separate command are needed; the use of a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`) ensures that the change to `IFS` is still localized, because command substitutions run in subshells.
- `${BASH_VERSINFO[*]: 0:3}` extracts the first 3 elements from array variable `$BASH_VERSINFO` (starting at index `0`, return `3` elements).

  - Note that in order for `IFS` to work as intended, `*` rather than `@` must be used to reference the array; `@` would *invariably* separate the elements with a single space each, irrespective of the value of `$IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

Building more on [FelixEnescu's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514057/6862601), here is a function that checks for just the major version or a combination of major and minor versions and returns 0 if the current Bash version is >= the needed version:

```
check_bash_version() {
    local major=${1:-4}
    local minor=$2
    local rc=0
    local num_re='^[0-9]+$'

    if [[ ! $major =~ $num_re ]] || [[ $minor && ! $minor =~ $num_re ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "ERROR: version numbers should be numeric"
        return 1
    fi
    if [[ $minor ]]; then
        local bv=${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}
        local vstring=$major.$minor
        local vnum=$major$minor
    else
        local bv=${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}
        local vstring=$major
        local vnum=$major
    fi
    ((bv < vnum)) && {
        printf '%s\n' "ERROR: Need Bash version $vstring or above, your version is ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}.${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}"
        rc=1
    }
    return $rc
}
```

It can be invoked as:

```
check_bash_version 4   # Check if 4.0 or above
check_bash_version 4 2 # Check if 4.2 or above
```

---

See the assertion related to this:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/f230fbacbb1d9fe48d68ce9302902fe2d3785dde/lib/assertions.sh#L12

Answer (score 1):

**Run** `bash --version` and then its output is like:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

or

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

or

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

---

**Use** Bash variable `$BASH_VERSION` and run `echo $BASH_VERSION`. Its output is like:

```
4.3.30(1)-release
```

---

**Usually** I use command `sed` to extract the version number, the following is the concrete command:

```
bash --version | sed -r -n 's@.*version (.*)\(1\)-release.*@\1@p'
```

For example:

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ bash --version | sed -r -n 's@.*version (.*)\(1\)-release.*@\1@p'
4.2.46
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

```
echo $BASH_VERSION | sed -r -n 's@(.*)\(1\)-release.*@\1@p'
```

For example:

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ echo $BASH_VERSION | sed -r -n 's@(.*)\(1\)-release.*@\1@p'
4.2.46
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of other responses with `BASH_VERSINFO`:

```sh
check_bash_version()
{
    local a=4 b=3   # Bash version >= a.b

    (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] > a || \
      (BASH_VERSINFO[0] == a && BASH_VERSINFO[1] >= b) )) || {
        echo "Error: Bash version >= $a.$b expected." >&2
        return 1
    }
}

check_bash_version || exit 1
```