# Checking if char is within set

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if some string from length 1 and has only following chars: [RGWBO].

I'm trying the following but it doesn't work, what am I missing?

```
if [[ !(${line[4]} =~ [RGWBO]) ]];
```

Comment: A fifth element in `$line`?

Comment: could you provide a sample of the dataset to clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
if [[ ${line[4]} =~ ^[RGWBO]+$ ]];
```

This means that the string right from the start till the end must have [RGWBO] characters one or more times.

If you want to negate the expression just use `!` in front of `[[ ]]`:

```
if ! [[ ${line[4]} =~ ^[RGWBO]+$ ]];
```

Or

```
if [[ ! ${line[4]} =~ ^[RGWBO]+$ ]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This one would work with any usable version of Bash:

```
[[ -n ${LINE[0]} && ${LINE[0]} != *[^RGWB0]* ]]
```

Even though I prefer the simplicity of extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ ${LINE[0]} == +([RGWBO]) ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

1. Test the string length with `${#myString}`, if it's egal to 1 proceed to step 2 ;
2. Does is contains your pattern.

### Code

```
re='[RGWBO]'; 
while read -r line; do
  if (( ${#line} == 1 )) && [[ $line == $re ]]; then
    echo "yes: $line"
  else 
    echo "no: $line" 
  fi
done < test.txt
```

### Resources

You may want to look at the following links:

- [Bash: Split string into character array's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930/bash-split-string-into-character-array) ;
- [Length of a string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Length_of_a_string), use `${#myString}` ;
- [Extracting parts of strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Extracting_parts_of_strings), use `${myString:0:8}` ;

### Data

The `test.txt` file contains this

```
RGWBO
RGWB
RGW
RG
R
G
W
B
O
V
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`expr`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html#EXPRREF) (expression evaluator) to do [substring matching](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern='[R|G|W|B|O]'
string=line[4]
res=`expr match "$string" $pattern`

if [ "${res}" -eq "1" ]; then
  echo 'match'
else
  echo 'doesnt match'
fi
```