# How do I convert a word into characters using the shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

How do I convert a word into characters using the shell script ?
As an example user to "u s e r"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: Split string into character array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930/bash-split-string-into-character-array)

Comment: Where is your attempt?  Did you even bother to put your exact title into google?  Several of the hits on the first page alone would solve your query.

Comment: If it had been tagged `bash`, that would open up using array indexes and a C-style for loop, e.g. `a=user; for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++)); do ((i == 0)) && b=${a:i:1} || b="$b ${a:i:1}"; done`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo user | sed 's/./& /g'
u s e r
```

Comment: Very clean use of `&` to refer to the portion of the pattern matched, and POSIX compliant as tagged.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this work fine in bash 4:

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(grep -o '.' <<<"user")

$ declare -p arr   #Just prints the array
declare -a arr=([0]="u" [1]="s" [2]="e" [3]="r")

$ echo "${arr[2]}"
e
```