# How can I split string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have a string of

```
samp_str="ABCDEF"
```

I want to split them up into chars like

```
var1=A
var2=B
var3=C
var4=D
var5=E
var6=F
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, so you want to print text like `VAl1=...` or you want to assign variable named `VAL1=some value` etc etc?

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/q/7578930/6245078](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7578930/6245078)

Answer (score 2):

About the only way I can think of to associate and store each character with a reference like `var0, var1, ...` in bash > 4 would be with the use of an *associative array*. If you just want to print the value next to a label `var0, var1, ...`, then you don't need to worry about storing anything, just split `var` into characters and `echo` a label next to each character.

If you don't care to give the individual characters any type of name, then a normal *indexed array* as Darby_Crash provided an example of in his answer is fine. It's actually less effort, but indexes will be all you have available.

However, if your intent is to be able to store the individual characters for later use, and then use a name to reference the characters later on, that's what an associative array is intended to provide.

For example, you can declare and associative array with `declare -A varname`. You can then use a *key* like the string made up of `var#` to store the character (e.g. `varname[var#]=char`). You can then later reference each character by providing the `var#` is the key (index) in normal array syntax to retrieve the character (e.g. `echo "var#=${varname[var#]}"`. In your case something like:

```
declare -A a                            ## declare associative array
var="ABCDEF"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#var}-1; i++)); do   ## loop over each char
a[var$i]=${var:i:1}                     ## assign under index 'var$i'
done

## output values saved in a
for ((i = 0; i < ${#var}; i++)); do
    echo "var$i=${a[var$i]}"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ (
>     declare -A a                            ## declare associative array
>     var="ABCDEF"
>     for ((i = 0; i < ${#var}; i++)); do     ## loop over each char
>     a[var$i]=${var:i:1}                     ## assign under index 'var$i'
>     done
>
>     ## output values saved in a
>     for ((i = 0; i < ${#var}; i++)); do
>         echo "var$i=${a[var$i]}"
>     done
> )
var0=A
var1=B
var2=C
var3=D
var4=E
var5=F
```

**note:** while you can iterate over an associative array using `for key in ${!varname[@]}; do`, that will not preserve any type of *sort-order* (associative arrays are unsorted). Above, since your references are made of of `var#`, simply looping over each `#` and using a derived key can preserve sort order. Granted, the benefit over an *indexed array* in doing it this way is obviously minimal.

Look over all answers and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Solid solution....@poh  does that answer your question? if so, it's nice to bother and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is my solution**

```
string='ABCDEF'
for ((i=1;i<=${#string};i++)); do eval "var$i=\"${string:$((i-1)):1}\""; done
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ echo $var1
A
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ echo $var2
B
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

**or you can do it using array (is the better method)**

```
string='ABCDEF'
for ((i=0;i<=${#string};i++)); do var[$i]="${string:i:1}"; done
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ echo "${var[0]}"
A
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ echo "${var[1]}"
B
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

Comment: Always worth dropping a note of caution about using `eval` sparingly when calling on a set of commands made up of variables. Like a bungled attempt to remove one directory that ends up deleting the entire root filesystem, (e.g.`var=; dir=$var/; command="sudo rm -r $dir"; eval $command`) very bad things can happen....

Comment: You're right but in this specific case is the less bad.

Comment: Yes agreed. But you know how new users are that find a new toy. Pretty soon they are daisy chaining loops together to eval `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you. You don't need to worry about the siz eof the string. It's calculated using this syntax `${#var}`,You will need to make the array  ends at `${#var} - 1`. lemme know if anything :)

```
 $ var="ABCDEF" ; for i in $(seq 0  $((${#var} - 1 )) ) ; do  echo var${i}=${var:${i}:1}  ; done
```

Outputs the follwing:

```
echo var0=A
echo var1=B
echo var2=C
echo var3=D
echo var4=E
echo var5=F
```

Comment: `$(seq 0  ${#var})` should be `$(seq 0  $((${#var} - 1)))`. bash array indexes are *zero* based (e.g. 6-char string has indexes `0-5`) Also, you are actually not storing anything for later reference. `"split them up"` is a bit ambiguous, but it appears he wants to assign to some storage for later use.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin for your feedback - I have updated length to be $((${#var} - 1 )). if you noticed my answer it, it says :  You will need to make the array ends at ${#var} - 1.

Answer (score 0):

A other way

```
samp_str="ABCDEF"
var+=
while read -n 1 c; do
  var+=("$c")
done<<<$samp_str
unset var[-1]
unset var[0]
for i in ${!var[*]} ; do
  echo var[$i] = ${var[$i]}
done
```