# Find the sum of a string of numbers in Bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash

So far I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo type in some numbers:
read input
```

From here on I'm stuck. Let's say `input=30790148`. What I want to do is add all of those integers up to get 3+0+7+9+0+1+4+8=32. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [relevant QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930/bash-split-string-into-character-array)

Comment: How would you do it mathematically?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way not using external tools:

```
read -p "Type some number: " num
for((i=0;i<${#num};i++)); do ((sum+=${num:i:1})); done

echo "$sum"
```

Comment: What is it doing: `${num:i:1}`. Seems like a number splitter, shifting one decimal -1- to the right by adding one to each fixed position `i`

Comment: @Timo It is a syntax for substrings. It means "return 1 character starting at ith character". Since `$num` is a "string", `${num:i:1}` is `bash`'s equivalent of `num[i]` in other languages.

Comment: Why not use $i here: `((sum+=${num:i:1}))`

Comment: It's not mandatory to use `$` in the arithmetic expansion `(( expr ))`. From manual: `...shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.`

Comment: ok, Using `((sum+=${num:i}))` without `1` will be a right shift by one reducing the array to the right.

Answer (score 2):

There are two core utilities, [`fold`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fold.html) and [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html), which you can use here (illustrated for `input=12345`):

```
fold -w1 <<< $input | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

- `fold -w1` wraps the input line to a width of 1 character:

  ```
  $ fold -w1 <<< $input
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  ```
- `paste -sd+ -` merges the input sequentially (`-s`), i.e., into a single line, with a `+` delimiter (`-d+`), reading from standard input (the final `-`; optional for GNU `paste`):

  ```
  $ fold -w1 <<< $input | paste -sd+ -
  1+2+3+4+5
  ```
- [`bc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html) then calculates the sum:

  ```
  $ fold -w1 <<< $input | paste -sd+ - | bc
  15
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This one using `sed` and `bc`

```
echo "12345" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\+0/g' | bc
```

It's a bit hackish though since the `+0` is not intuitive

Edit: Using `&` from @PaulHodges' answer, this would shorten to:

```
echo "12345" | sed 's/./&+0/g' | bc
```

Comment: This works fine with `bc`, but watch out with prepending zeroes to numbers; in some places, the number will suddenly be interpreted as octal.

Comment: Yeah, it's really abusing the fact that `bc` will interpret everything here as decimal. I was gunning for the shortest code possible e.g. `sed 's/./&+0/g' | bc`

Comment: I can't think of anything right now, but imagine a tool that got fed `1+02+09+0`. Since `09` is not a valid octal number, it would definitely error out.

Comment: Sorry, figured out what you meant and deleted my comment, lol

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner may help you:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i}END{print s}' FS="" <<< yourString
```

for example:

```
kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i}END{print s}' FS=""<<< "123456789" 
45
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` and `bc` -

```
input=30790148; echo $input | sed 's/[0-9]/&+/g; s/$/0/;' | bc
```

If you don't have GNU `sed` you might need to line break the commands instead of using a semicolon.

```
input=30790148;
echo $input | 
  sed '
     s/[0-9]/&+/g
      s/$/0/
  ' | bc
```

Comment: Hey, we can merge our answers and simplify it further `sed 's/./&+0/g' | bc`. TIL of `&`, thank you.

Comment: c.f. the comments on your answer - add the 0 separately at the end.

Comment: Yep, I was only trying to make it as short as possible. Anyway, thanks for `&`, another tool in the toolbox.