# Vim E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#' for using '#' to find out the length of a string

Tags: bash, vim

I have this one-liner command, that outputs every letter of a string in a line:

```
❯ a="string"; for ((i=0; i<${#a}; i++)); do echo "${a:$i:1}"; done

s
t
r
i
n
g
```

But if I execute the same command in VIM:

`:r !a="string"; for ((i=0; i<${#a}; i++)); do echo "${a:$i:1}"; done`

I get the following error:

```
E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#'
```

How can I fix this?

I'm trying to insert those lines into VIM.

Comment: [vi.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-special there are some characters that are special in `:` commands. You need to escape the `#`.

Comment: Also you could save looping with shell using `a="string"; fold -w1 <<<"$a"`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579022/7939871

Comment: @Barmar Escaping works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a command-line, Vim allows certain special placeholders to refer to the current (or alternate) file name. This is useful both for Ex commands (e.g. `:split #`) and shell commands (e.g. `:! python %`).

As a consequence, these characters need to be escaped (by prepending a backslash) if they should be taken literally; [`:help cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special) explains this.

In your case, it's just the `#` that needs to be escaped:

```
:r !a="string"; for ((i=0; i<${\#a}; i++)); do echo "${a:$i:1}"; done
```

PS: If you had just followed [`:help E194`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#E194), it would have already hinted at the fact that the `#` is to blame. Vim's help is really good.