# How to print a string letter by letter in Linux - bash shell

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, for-loop

I have a string and want to print each character line by line.

Input:

```
str="Hello World"
```

Expected Output:

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

I tried below script, got different output

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="Hello World"

for i in ${txt[*]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

My output:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579022/3833426)

Comment: If you must store it in an array, then `readarray txt <<< $(echo "Hello World" |grep -o .)` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

Using `read's` ability to read `n` characters at a time:

```
while read -r -n1 i
do
    echo "$i"
done <<< "$str"
```

Using `bash's` substring ability:

```
for ((i=0;i<"${#str}";i++))
do
    echo "${str:i:1}"
done
```

Feeding `str` to `grep` as a here-string:

```
grep -o . <<< "${str}"
```

All of these generate:

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

Comment: Why not use the `readarray` bash builtin?

Comment: Why make a copy of the data (one copy in `str`, one copy in an array), and still require a loop (`while` vs `for`), just to print single-character lines? Nothing in OP's question indicates a need for, or a benefit from, an array.