# Should I use Python casefold?

Tags: python, python-3.x, case-folding

Been recently reading on casefold and string comparisons when ignoring case. I've read that the MSDN standard is to use InvariantCulture and definitely avoid toLowercase. However, casefold from what I have read is like a more aggressive toLowercase. My question is should I use casefold in Python or is there a more pythonic standard to use instead? Also, does casefold pass the Turkey Test?

Comment: 1. What `casefold` does is explained [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold). 2. What does *"better"* mean in this case? 3. What's the Turkish Test (and have you tried running it to find out)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, meant more pythonic and also meant Turkey Test. I just want to know what good programmers use when they want to do caseless comparisons in python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - the turkish test is described in more detail here http://stackoverflow.com/a/797043/135978

Comment: Have you tried casefold to see for yourself whether it passes the Turkey Test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just honestly haven't had the time to try it. I also haven't encountered a situation where I would need to use casefold yet. This was just a question that I had in my mind after doing some idle research. I'll be sure to post my results if I do get to testing it though. In the end, my biggest question is still: Is casefold the most pythonic way to ignore case?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1) In Python 3, [`casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) should be used to implement caseless string matching.**

Starting with Python 3.0, strings are stored as Unicode. [The Unicode Standard Chapter 3.13](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf) defines the *default caseless matching* as follows:

> A string X is a caseless match for a string Y if and only if:
> toCasefold(X) = toCasefold(Y)

[Python's `casefold()` implements the Unicode's `toCasefold()`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) So, it should be used to implement caseless string matching. Although, casefolding alone is not enough to cover some corner cases and to pass the Turkey Test (see Point 3).

**2) As of Python 3.6, casefold() cannot pass the Turkey Test.**

For two characters, uppercase I and dotted uppercase I, [the Unicode Standard defines two different casefolding mappings.](http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/CaseFolding.txt)

*The default (for non-Turkic languages):*
I → i  (U+0049 → U+0069)
İ → i̇  (U+0130 → U+0069 U+0307)

*The alternative (for Turkic languages):*
I → ı  (U+0049 → U+0131)
İ → i  (U+0130 → U+0069)

Pythons `casefold()` can apply only the default mapping and fails the Turkey Test. For example, the Turkish words "LİMANI" and "limanı" are caseless equivalents, but `"LİMANI".casefold() == "limanı".casefold()` returns `False`. There is no option to enable the alternative mapping.

**3) How to do caseless string matching in Python 3.**

[The Unicode Standard Chapter 3.13](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf) describes several caseless matching algorithms. The *canonical casless matching* would probably suit most use cases. This algorithm already takes into account all corner cases. We only need to add an option to switch between non-Turkic and Turkic casefolding.

```
import unicodedata

def normalize_NFD(string):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', string)

def casefold_(string, include_special_i=False):
    if include_special_i:
        string = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', string)
        string = string.replace('\u0049', '\u0131')
        string = string.replace('\u0130', '\u0069')
    return string.casefold()

def casefold_NFD(string, include_special_i=False):
    return normalize_NFD(casefold_(normalize_NFD(string), include_special_i))

def caseless_match(string1, string2, include_special_i=False):
    return  casefold_NFD(string1, include_special_i) == casefold_NFD(string2, include_special_i)
```

`casefold_()` is a wrapper for Python's `casefold()`. If its parameter `include_special_i` is set to `True`, then it applies the Turkic mapping, and if it is set to `False` the default mapping is used.

`caseless_match()` does the canonical casless matching for `string1` and `string2`. If the strings are Turkic words, `include_special_i` parameter must be set to `True`.

**Examples:**

```
>>> caseless_match('LİMANI', 'limanı', include_special_i=True)
True
```

```
>>> caseless_match('LİMANI', 'limanı')
False
```

```
>>> caseless_match('INTENSIVE', 'intensive', include_special_i=True)
False
```

```
>>> caseless_match('INTENSIVE', 'intensive')
True
```

Comment: Nice work.  `casefold_` function doesn't need to end in a `_` since it is not shadowing a builtin or keyword.

Comment: alternatively there is PyICU's implementation of casefolding  which has an optional parameter to include the Turkisc casefolding rules in Unicode to full casefolding.