# Guava getIfPresent() Incorrect return

Tags: java, enums, guava

I am trying to use guava's `getIfPresent()` for an enum as below:

```
private enum LegalColumns
{

    PRODUCERS_CUT("PRODUCER'S CUT", PMCColumnsEnum.NETWORK_CUT_1.getColumnName()),
    PROPOSED_LOCKED_CUT("PROPOSED LOCKED CUT", PMCColumnsEnum.NETWORK_CUT_3.getColumnName()),
    LOCK("LOCK", PMCColumnsEnum.LOCKED_DELIVERY.getColumnName()),
    FINAL_MIX("FINAL MIX", PMCColumnsEnum.MIX_DATE.getColumnName());

    private String column;
    private String replacementColumn;

    LegalColumns(String column, String replacementColumn) {
        this.column = column;
        this.replacementColumn = replacementColumn;
    }


    public static LegalColumns getIfPresent(String column) {
        System.out.println(Enums.getIfPresent(LegalColumns.class, column.trim().toUpperCase()));
        return Enums.getIfPresent(LegalColumns.class, column.toUpperCase()).orNull();
    }
}
```

When I step through this however, it always prints out `Optional.absent()` despite the strings being exact matches. I followed, to my knowledge, the guava spec exactly. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: What `column` value do you pass?

Comment: I have gone with another approach, but for others, I passed in columns like "FINAL MIX".

Answer (score 1):

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#getIfPresent(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

> Returns an optional enum constant for the given type, using
>   Enum.valueOf(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String). If the constant
>   does not exist, Optional.absent() is returned. A common use case is
>   for parsing user input or falling back to a default enum constant. For
>   example, Enums.getIfPresent(Country.class,
>   countryInput).or(Country.DEFAULT);

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html?is-external=true#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to
>   declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace
>   characters are not permitted.)

From your comment

> I have gone with another approach, but for others, I passed in columns like "FINAL MIX".

"FINAL MIX" != "FINAL_MIX"

Guava uses the enum identifier, not the string you pass into the constructor.

So for the enum instance, `FINAL_MIX("FINAL MIX", PMCColumnsEnum.MIX_DATE.getColumnName());` the enum identifier is "FINAL_MIX" not the string you pass in "FINAL MIX"

IN ADDITION! as you do not define a Locale on your string.toUpperCase, you are at risk of the [turkey I bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796986/what-is-the-turkey-test).