# Can't post "İ" letter to web server in English device language

Tags: java, android, locale

In my project, that should post turkey country name as "TÜRKİYE" with uppercase letter to the web server. But it doesn't work when I change device language to English. Because It post "TÜRKIYE". Uppercase I. I must fix it and it should post "İ". How can I do this?

```
       String from1 = textV_fromCity_ac_search.getText().toString();
            String to1 = textV_toCity_ac_search.getText().toString();
            if (isValidData() && isValidDate() && hasSessionId()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("SessionId", User.getInstance().getSessionId());
                intent.putExtra("PassengerNumber", textV_passenger_number.getText().toString());
                String[] dataX = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
                for (String aDataX : dataX) {
                    if (aDataX.equals(textV_fromCity_ac_search.getText().toString() + " (Türkiye)")) {
                        from1 = aDataX;
                    } else if (aDataX.equals(textV_toCity_ac_search.getText().toString() + " (Türkiye)")) {
                        to1 = aDataX;
                    }
                }
                intent.putExtra(MyConstants.BUNDLE_FROM, from1);
                intent.putExtra(MyConstants.BUNDLE_TO, to1);
                intent.putExtra(MyConstants.BUNDLE_ISDOMESTIC, from1.toUpperCase().contains("TÜRKİYE") && to1.toUpperCase().contains("TÜRKİYE"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: A [mcve] should help here - we'd need to know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry. I thought this is an easy way for it. Whatever I will post my code.

Comment: As a workaround, would the solution also work with `toLowerCase()` ?

Comment: @JensV No. That's not what I want.

Comment: @Shayma if you think it's easy, then you should find it easy to find the answer!

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Look. You can't understand or I can't tell it. There is problem only the device don't post uppercase of i. It post uppercase of ü. The uppercase of ü is not english letter right? But it can post that ü. It can't post uppercase i. So its the specific problem. So, I thought there is an answer that I don't know.

Comment: `ü` to `Ü` works because that's the default mapping just as `i` to `I` is. However, depending on the locale there _might_ be special mappings (such as in your case) and thus you need to provide the locale you want to be used or otherwise you just get the standard mapping.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uppercase `String` using `Locale`. By default, `toUpperCase` method uses system's default `Locale`. But you can change this by `locale` parameter.

```
String uppercased = "Türkiye".toUpperCase(new Locale("tr","TR"));
```

**Edit:** Ok, I'm editing an answer in order to clear things.

Also you may want to look at "The Turkey Test": [What is The Turkey Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796986/what-is-the-turkey-test)

In an i18n perspective, localization of Turkish significantly different than other locales.

For example, for latters:

```
Lowercase I -> ı 
Uppercase i -> İ
```

In Java, default locale is provided by the system. But in your case, you want to use Turkish locale explicity. If you want to uppercase the string "Türkiye" to "TÜRKİYE" regardless of the system language, you should provide Turkish locale explicity.

In order to achieve that, instead of using `String#toUpperCase()` method you need to use `String#toUpperCase(Locale)` method.

Comment: The problem is when it post in device with English language. It don't post this "İ" and make it "I". But it post truth "Ü". I need post "İ" also. Thats the problem.

Comment: `"Türkiye".toUpperCase(new Locale("tr","TR"));` outputs `TÜRKİYE`. When you uppercase with `locale` parameter, device language won't affect your result.

Thing that I say, use `toUpperCase(Locale)` method instead of `toUpperCase()` method.

Comment: But this upperCase(Locale) method occurs syntax error. Also I get this TÜRKİYE from array.xml not from string.

Comment: @Shayma your code contains `from1.toUpperCase().contains("TÜRKİYE")` - that indicates that `from1` contains lowercase characters. If you read the Javadoc on `toUppercase()` you'll see that the special handling of `i` in Turkish is explicitly mentioned - that's why you need to provide the locale for that special case because the system's default locale might produce another mapping, i.e. `i` -> `I`.

Comment: @Thomas Ok. Yes I understand that system's default produce this mapping. Ok I will read Javadoc.