# Python: lower() method generates wrong letter in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, decode, encode

```
text = 'ÇEKİM GÜNÜ KALİTESİNİ DÜZENLERLSE'

sentence = text.split(' ')
print(sentence)

if "ÇEKİM" in sentence:
    print("yes-1")

print(" ")
sentence_ = text.lower().split(' ')
print(sentence_)
   
if "çekim" in sentence_:
    print("yes-2")

>> output: 

['ÇEKİM', 'GÜNÜ', 'KALİTESİNİ', 'DÜZENLERLSE']
yes-1
 
['çeki̇m', 'günü', 'kali̇tesi̇ni̇', 'düzenlerlse']
```

I have a problem about string. I have a sentence like a text. When I check a specific word in this sentence-splitted list, I can find "ÇEKİM" word (prints yes). However, while I make search by lowering sentence, I can not find in the list because it changes "i" letter. What is the reason of it (encoding/decoding) ? Why "lower()" method changes string in addition to lowering ?  Btw, it is a turkish word. Upper:ÇEKİM - Lower:çekim

Comment: You used an ASCII lower case `i` in the literal string `"çekim"`, but `'İ'.lower()` does not give just the ASCII lower case `i`.  It gives 'i' followed by [Unicode Character 'COMBINING DOT ABOVE' (U+0307)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

Comment: Related: https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt and https://bugs.python.org/issue34723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turkish i and English i are treated differently.  Capitalized Turkish i is İ, while capitalized English i is I.  To differentiate Unicode has rules for converting to lower and upper case.  Lowercase Turkish i has a combining mark.  Also, converting the lower case version to upper case leaves the characters in a decomposed form, so proper comparison needs to normalize the string to a standard form.  You can't compare a decomposed form to a composed form.  Note the differences in the strings below:

```
#coding:utf8
import unicodedata as ud

def dump_names(s):
    print('string:',s)
    for c in s:
        print(f'U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
    
turkish_i = 'İ'
dump_names(turkish_i)
dump_names(turkish_i.lower())
dump_names(turkish_i.lower().upper())
dump_names(ud.normalize('NFC',turkish_i.lower().upper()))
```

```
string: İ
  U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE
string: i̇
  U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
  U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE
string: İ
  U+0049 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
  U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE
string: İ
  U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE
```

Some terminals also have display issues.  My system displays '' with the dot over the m, not the i.  For example, on the Chrome browser, below displays correctly:

```
>>> s = 'ÇEKİM'
>>> s.lower()
'çeki̇m'
```

But on one of my editors it displays as:

[image: Image of editor with dot over m]

So it appears something like this is what the OP is seeing.  The following comparison will work:

```
if "çeki\N{COMBINING DOT ABOVE}m" in sentence_:
    print("yes-2")
```

Comment: Yes. I tested and it is correct. Can one solution be to transform all special characters like "İ" to the English language format "I" ? or do you have any alternative?

Comment: @Mehmet I'm no expert in Turkish, but misspelling the word doesn't seem like the best solution.  Turkish has a dotless upper/lower (I/ı) as well that has similar problems.

Comment: @Mehmet See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I and [What is the Turkey Test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/796986/235698).